# Technique or Pattern to calculate conditional statement

Tags: algorithms

I am attempting to create a conditional statement that compares four (4) true/false conditions. Depending on the state of these four conditions (either true or false) the conditional statement will either pass or fail. I have a table that tells me the outcome (pass/fail) of all possible permutations. 2^4 = 16 possible permutations.

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|             |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass |  Pass | Fail |  Fail |  Fail |  Fail |  Fail |  Fail |  Fail |  Fail |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Condition A |  True |  True | False | False | False |  True |  True | False | True | False |  True |  True |  True | False | False | False |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Condition B |  True |  True | False | False |  True | False | False |  True | True |  True | False | False |  True | False |  True | False |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Condition C | False |  True |  True | False |  True |  True | False | False | True |  True |  True | False | False |  True | False | False |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Condition D | False | False |  True |  True | False | False | False |  True | True |  True |  True |  True |  True | False | False | False |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is there a pattern/technique I can use to translate this matrix to a conditional statement such as the following ...

```
if (A == True && (B == True || C == False || D == True))
{
  // Pass code here
}
else
{
  // Fail code here
}
```

Just to clarify, it is the conditional statement that I am trying to calculate `(A == True && (B == True || C == False || D == True))` in the above example. In the future I may have more or less permutations and I am trying to determine a pattern/technique other than trial or error to generate the conditional statement.

Comment: Why not construct the boolean expressions from the *pass* columns, `or` them together to form a single large expression, and apply [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) to simplify? If the number of variables gets too large, use some heuristic since the problem is NP-complete.

Comment: There's also a graphical / visual tool called a Karnaugh map that can help you put together minimal boolean expressions (typically in sum-of-products form). It's easier to visualize one when you only have a small number of variables, but 4 is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use the direct binary representations of your conditions. That means that, e.g. the first two columns could be represented by:

(A True, B True, C False , D False)   --> ( 1100)
(A True, B True, C True  , D False)   --> ( 1110)
...

You can then define your conditions expressed by your columns as bitsets:

```
                                          //[A,B,C,D]
std::bitset<4> column_one_condition(12); // [1,1,0,0]
std::bitset<4> column_two_condition(14); // [1,1,1,0]
...
```

When you have done that, the input you get can be compared to your conditions via the == operator.

```
if(input_bitset ==column_one_condition) { pass();}
if(input_bitset ==column_two_condition) { pass();}
                ...
```

This might not be super intuitive, but it should be lightning fast and also extensible when adding more conditions. Also, this takes one line per condition. If you do the full if-then-else syntax the same logic will get out of hand fast.

It should also be possible to use a matrix (2D bool array) to represent your table and code up methods evaluating your input against this matrix.
This might be even more compact, but possibly not as readable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the if-then-else variant you posted can be shortened further by using the negation "!". If the number of conditions stays relatively low, you can do one-liners like this:

```
if( A and  B and !C and !D) pass();
if( A and  B and  C and !D) pass();
if( A and  B and !C and !D) pass();
if(!A and !B and  C and  D) pass();
if(!A and !B and !C and  D) pass();
// ...
if( A and  B and  C and  D) fail();
```

As you stated, the amount of lines you need grows exponentially, so at some point this gets very much boilerplate code.